# What is the difference between drupal/drupal and drupal-composer/drupal-project packages?

Tags: composer

I want to use composer with my future Drupal projects. I installed Composer on my machine and I noticed two packages (drupal/drupal and drupal-composer/drupal-project). When I install the second package, I get a warning message telling that there is no stable version.

What are the difference between those two package?
Is it composer enough for Drupal, or should I use Drush with it?

Comment: See my question for an answer that gives a little bit of info about this: [How do I update Drupal core on composer install?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186913/how-do-i-update-drupal-core-on-composer-install)

Answer (score 4):

```
drupal/drupal
```

This is the main repository for the Drupal project and is used to generate the tarball which is available for download on Drupal.org. This package is not used (directly) if you are using Composer to manage your codebase.

```
drupal/core
```

This is a subtree split of drupal/drupal repository which contains everything in the parent repo's `/core` directory. This is the package that is used if you are using Composer to manage your codebase.

```
drupal-composer/drupal-project
```

This is a "scaffold" project and serves as a starting point for your root composer.json file. This package isn't maintained by the Drupal Association, but it has become the de facto standard for assembling a Drupal codebase with Composer. It does a few things:

1. It brings in the `drupal/core` package and couple other requirements needed to assemble and run a Drupal site (composer/installers, cweagans/composer-patches) and a few nice-to-haves (drupal/console, webflo/drupal-finder, ...).
2. In addition to the packages listed above, it requires the `drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold` package which is responsible for assembling all the stuff normally provided as part of the tarball that's needed to run a Drupal site that lives *outside* of the /core directory (index.php, update.php, etc).
3. Contains instructions for composer/installers that tells Composer where to put stuff like modules and profiles.
4. Defines the Drupal-specific packagist repository.

Typically, you don't require or clone scaffold projects. They are intended to be used as starting points for projects of your own. You would use the `create-project` command instead:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project
```

There are other scaffold projects out there with more opinions or different focuses ([BLT](https://github.com/acquia/blt-project), Drupal CI) and most D8 Distributions provide a scaffold project ([Open Social](https://github.com/goalgorilla/social_template), [Lightning](https://github.com/acquia/lightning-project), [Thunder](https://github.com/BurdaMagazinOrg/thunder-project), etc)