# What is drupal/drupal dev-master?

Tags: composer, workbench

I have a Drupal 8.6.7 project that I'm trying to manage with Composer. I'm trying to understand why I cannot make it work. To get this project started, I wiped the vendor and composer.lock file and ran
`composer install --with-dependencies`
Now I want to install a contributed module.

`composer require drupal/workbench`
Composer returns the following:

> Problem 1
>
> ```
> - don't install drupal/core 8.6.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
> - remove drupal/drupal dev-master|remove drupal/core 8.6.7
> - don't install drupal/core 8.6.7|remove drupal/drupal dev-master
> - Installation request for drupal/drupal dev-master -> satisfiable by drupal/drupal[dev-master].
> - Installation request for drupal/core (locked at 8.6.7, required as ^8.6) -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.6.7].
> ```

OK, there's something about drupal/core that's installed that is conflicting with this module. Except, the Composer output leaves me confused, as I have a working core 8.6.7.
The composer tools are not in play at this point.
`composer why-not drupal/workbench` and `composer prohibit drupal/workbench` fail because the module was never installed.

So I was looking through my composer.lock to figure out "remove drupal/drupal dev-master". What am I looking for?
Not that I want to, but I need to figure this out and would like some help and the clues as to what Composer has installed is in the lock file. Going thermonuclear and reinstalling after manually adding this module in composer.json brings other issues.

My composer.json

```
{
"name": "drupal/drupal",
"description": "Drupal is an open source content management platform powering millions of websites and applications.",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"require": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.6",
    "composer/installers": "^1.0.24",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4",
    "drupal/address": "^1.4",
    "commerceguys/intl": "~0.7",
    "drush/drush": "^9.1.0",
    "drupal/ds": "^3",
    "drupal/menu_link_attributes": "^1.0",
    "drupal/redirect": "^1.0.0",
    "drupal/google_analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "drupal/console":"~1.0"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8"
},
"extra": {
    "merge-plugin": {
        "include": [
            "core/composer.json"
        ],
        "recurse": true,
        "replace": false,
        "merge-extra": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
        "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
        "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
        "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
        "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
        "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
        "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\": "core/lib/Drupal/Core/Composer"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::preAutoloadDump",
    "post-autoload-dump": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::ensureHtaccess",
    "post-package-install": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "post-package-update": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::vendorTestCodeCleanup",
    "drupal-phpunit-upgrade-check": "Drupal\\Core\\Composer\\Composer::upgradePHPUnit",
    "drupal-phpunit-upgrade": "@composer update phpunit/phpunit phpspec/prophecy symfony/yaml --with-dependencies --no-progress",
    "phpcs": "phpcs --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --",
    "phpcbf": "phpcbf --standard=core/phpcs.xml.dist --runtime-set installed_paths $($COMPOSER_BINARY config vendor-dir)/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer --"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: did you try with `composer require 'drupal/workbench:^1.1'` ?

Comment: Another wild guess: Your project with customized `composer.json` has the name `drupal/drupal` (just the first line of your `composer.json`). So in your case, `drupal/drupal` @dev-master is actually your own project. - I remember the composer templates for Drupal 8 even have a conflict `"drupal/drupal": "*"` line, which may add to your issue. Did you try with a custom project namespace as, e.g. `sam/my_project`?

Comment: I think this is more about this question [What is the difference between drupal/drupal and drupal-composer/drupal-project packages?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187018/what-is-the-difference-between-drupal-drupal-and-drupal-composer-drupal-project)

Comment: Thank you for your input. It is helping to shed light. Reading the link @4kr suggests that the "name" attribute s/b "drupal/core"?

Comment: @Mario Steinitz when you suggest a custom project namespace is new to me. Searching for that phrase did not shed light on how to do this to help isolate the issue?